# Morphisms between lax wedges

Tags: ct.category-theory

In the paper

> BOZAPALIDES, S., *Les fins cartésiennes*

the following definition of a *lax wedge* for a 2-functor $S\colon \mathcal{A}^{op}\times \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal B$ between 2-categories is given: it is a collection $\underline\omega$ of 1- and 2-cells
$$\begin{gather*}
\big\{\omega_A\colon E\to S(A,A) \big\}_{A\in\cal A}\\
\big\{ \omega_f\colon S(f,B)\cdot\omega_B \Rightarrow S(A,f)\cdot\omega_A\big\}_{f\in\hom(\cal A)}
\end{gather*}$$ 
such that the squares

[image]

expressing a lax wedge condition are all commutative. These 2-cells must satisfy suitable coherence laws with respect to composition of 1-cells $a\stackrel{f}\to a'\stackrel{f'}\to a''$ and 2-cells $\lambda\colon f\to f'$: the diagrams of 2-cells

[image]

must be equal, and the diagrams of 2-cells

[image]

must also be equal. Also, $\omega_{1_a} = 1_{\omega_a}$.

Once this is done, the author defines a morphism between lax wedges to be a collection of 2-cells $\{\Theta_a\colon \omega_a\to \sigma_a\}$ such that the "obvious" commutativity holds.

[image]

But he seems to define this notion only for lax wedges having the same domain!

This doesn't seem reasonable to me, if one wants to recover the notion of "lax end" (which is precisely what Bozapalides wants to achieve).

Am I missing something important?

Comment: Wedges and modifications as defined will make up a category LaxWedge(A, S), functorially in A.  The lax end will then be a representation of this functor.  So there's no problem.  The kind of wedge-morphism you're (probably) thinking about will be a morphism in the 2-category of elements of this functor, part of another way of expressing the end's universal property.  (Am I making sense?)

Comment: This point should be clearer now, after a bit of meditation. I am maybe confused by the fact that there are several flavours for the laxity of a functor between 2-categories. If you put some nonidentity 2-cells in the diagrams above you obtain co/ends for co/lax and pseudo functors between 2-categories. Can lax natural transformations be expressed again as ends? And what about the other "pillars" of co/end calculus?